# Replacing main html file for a specific bower package

Tags: dependencies, overriding, bower

Hullo..

I'm using a shiny new bower user :)

I'm working at an existing angular project and want to change main html file for one of the dependencies included in my project's bower.json.

I've tried using the override tag as follows

```
"overrides": {
    "MY_PACKAGE": {
      "main": [
        "REPLACEMENT_FILE_IN_PUBLIC_DIRECTORY"
      ]
    }
```

However this doesn't seem to have an impact.

Any idea about what I'm doing wrong?

Many thanks